# Editable Div not firing "KeyUp" event/ Removing Highlighting

Tags: javascript, jquery, highlight, contenteditable, jquery-events

I am using an editable div:

```
<div class="editableDiv"  contenteditable="true">
   sdtgssdrsdrtyy ╚asasasarrstssdertrtyrtyrrty ☻aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaadaafsdsf4n
</div>
```

I am having task to show non-ascii characters to the user, to highlight the non-ascii characters I have used the highlighting jQuery library which highlights the non-ascii characters by adding span with "highlight" class.
The innerHTML is as follow:

```
<span class="highlight">╚</span>asasasarrstssdertrtyrtyrrty
<span class="highlight">☻</span>aaaaaaaaaaaaaadaafsdsf4n
```

Highlighting works well,but only problem arise is that when user delete the non-ascii characters and starts typing from that position the typed characters also gets highlighted, when I checked the innerHTML it shows that newly typed characters also got into the span tag as follow:

```
<span class="highlight">☻aaa</span>aaaaaaaaaaaaaadaafsdsf4n
```

To solve this issue I used the `KeyUp` event on editable div and in this event I am separating the span with non-ascii characters and newly typed characters and putting them into the new span tag and replacing old one. This works fine for the first ``keyup` and the newly entered characters also doesn't have the highlighting but after that when I type again this event doesn't fire.

I don't have clue as what is causing this? Is this because I have changed the innerHTML of the div explicitly? Please help.

Following is the `keyup` function:

```
$(document).on('keyup', ".editableDiv", function () {
        
        var hilighterSpans = $(this).children(".highlight");

        hilighterSpans.each(function (x, y) {

            var spanText = $(y).text().trim();

            if (spanText == "") {
                $(y).remove();
            }
            else {

                var regex = new RegExp("[^\u0020-\u007E]+");
                var nonasciiChar = regex.exec(spanText);
                
                if (nonasciiChar != "") {

                    var asciiChars = spanText.replace(nonasciiChar, '');

                    var spannode1 = document.createElement('span');

                    var spannode2 = document.createElement('span');
                    spannode2.className = 'highlight';
                    spannode2.innerHTML=nonasciiChar;
                    
                    if (spanText.indexOf(nonasciiChar) == 0) {
                        $(spannode1).append(spannode2);
                        $(spannode1).append(asciiChars);                        
                    }
                    else {
                        $(spannode1).append(asciiChars);
                        $(spannode1).append(spannode2);                        
                    }

                    $(this).replaceWith(spannode1);
                }
            }
        });    
      
    });
```

Replaced innerHTML is as follow:

```
<span><span class="highlight">╚</span>assd</span>
<span><span class="highlight">☻</span>aaa</span>
```

can this be causing problem?

[JSFiddle for this problem](http://jsfiddle.net/qrk69ben/)

I JSFiddle try typing right from the highlighted non-ascii character..... I want new typed characters to be unhighlighted.... currently for first typing it works fine (though the new typed characters changed positions, will have to look in to this)... but if typed again the code doesn't work (`keyup` event doesn't fire up)...

Comment: If memory serves me, you need to add a `tabindex` attribute to the div for some browsers to fire those events.

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: It doesn't look like the problem is with the `keyup` or any event. It's about the highlight adding elements and you need to remove them if the user changes the highlighted text.

Comment: @MelanciaUK: yes i am doing the same thing...if user deletes the highighted nonascii characters i am removing the whole span...but if he trys to type without removing highlighted characters, i am separating the newly tyed chars from the highlighted nonascii characters so that he wont see the newly typed chars highlighted... this works for the first keyup...but after that if i try to type the event doesn't fire...

Comment: Can you create a `jsFiddle` for us to see it working?

Comment: please see this link http://jsfiddle.net/qrk69ben/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for this problem and thought to share it with you guys so it could help other people.

Adding to the rogelio's solutiuon i.e. making span contenteditable="false",i have added "[Zero Width Space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm)"("&#8203") at the end of each highlighting span,which solved the issue.

[JS Fiddle For the Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/xxvwhx22/).

```
    <div class="editableDiv"  contenteditable="true">sdtgssdrsdrtyy
<span class="highlight" contenteditable="false">╚</span>&#8203;asasasarrstssdertrtyrtyrrty
<span class="highlight" contenteditable="false">☻</span>&#8203;aaaaaaaaaaaaaadaafsdsf4n</div>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: up for the solution you have found but try to copy and paste the ASCI char and then start typing from next to asci char it will highlight all char i type...      you have any solution for that?!

Answer (score 5):

The issue is because the inner `.highlight` span is editable too.

You need to set the `spannode2` to `contenteditable="false"`, add this line after you create the `spannode2` element.

```
spannode2.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'false');
```

Be sure the initial `.highlight` is setted to `contenteditable="false"`.

In short, all of `.highlight` span must have `contenteditable="false"`.

See the [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qrk69ben/1/)

Comment: I will have to see if this could be achieve..as the highlighting spans are created by third party jquery library...i m going to try this...Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Anyway, you can do this `$('.highlight').attr('contenteditable','false');` after the plugin creates the spans.

Comment: I am having issue in IE,after making span noneditable when I click after the highlighted span text the cursor automatically mives forward and also it is not allowing me to delete the content..It's working fine in Chrome...please advise

Comment: I cannot test on IE. But in firefox happens something similar. I had to click over the next character after the highlighted, but I don't know how to fix it yet.

Answer (score 0):

it's actually bug in firefox that ignores delete and backspace event when "< span >" is nested inside other element set contenteditable "true"...

you can check bug through this link :)
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=685452

Comment: what is the solution for this...same is happening in IE